# textbox only number using javascript on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html

Another way to only allow input numbers on textbox using javascript, when browsing using the mobile browser

```js
function validatenumber(vtitle,vtxt)
{
    var amt=document.getElementById(vtxt).value;
    var mb=amt.substring((amt.length-1), amt.length);
    if(mb!="")
    {
        if((mb==0||mb==1||mb==2||mb==3||mb==4||mb==5||mb==6||mb==7||mb==8||mb==9)&&mb!=" ")
        {               
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(vtxt).value=amt.substring(0, (amt.length-1));
            alert(vtitle+" must in number");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeyup="validatenumber('Title extra7','extra7')">
```

[Sentrapedagang.com](http://www.sentrapedagang.com)

Comment: Why don't you just use `<input type="number">`?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
```

and if you are using HTML5 then you can simply use:

```
<input type="number">
```